# Pre-select a checkbox from an exposed filter

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that lists blog articles. The blog content type has a taxonomy reference field to the 'tags' vocabulary, authors can select 1 or multiple tags. The view exposes the 'Has taxonomy terms (with depth) (exposed)' filter (as a list of checkboxes) so that users can search for blog articles containing 1 or more tags.

Now, i'm trying to pre-select 1 of the checkboxes that are exposed to the user in the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() hook. It should be a simple as the code below but it just doesn't work. The tag i'm trying to pre-select has the ID 288.

What am i doing wrong?

```php
function xtheme_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-vcon-finder-page-1') {
    $form['tags']['#default_value'] = [288 => 288];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the value needs to be just `288` or `'288'` instead of an array.

Comment: Hey leymannx, thx for your answer... I already tried that, does not work. In fact, if you pre-select the checkbox directly in the drupal view UI, catch the form object in the preprocess hook using xdebug than you see the #default_value in the associatieve array notation 288:288